# Javascript to enable and disable fields and also to validate a form

Tags: javascript

If animal (in 4b) is selected then the following fields should be enabled:

i) Type of animal (use same list as in 3b above), age (in months), sex (male, female: choose
one), colour (black, brown, gray, white: chose one or more). (Up to 5% bonus points for
the usage of the colour palette)

ii) Months owned

iii) Date of last vet visit, name of vet, phone number for the vet

iv) reasons for surrendering animal

d) If monetary service (in 4b) is selected then the following fields should be enabled: amount
requested and type of payment (cheque, cash, credit card: choose one)

e) If service is selected (in 4b), state whether full time or part time (choose one), and number of
days per week (1-7). Note. Only one type of service information should be enabled upon
the user’s selection, whilst the others are disabled

Comment: And what's your question?  How to write JavaScript code?  Have you started with some tutorials on JavaScript?

Comment: You need to make an effort to show us you've tried something and can't get it to work. Just copying and pasting a question isn't going to get you any help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you've tried, and to explain which part you're having trouble with. (In the meantime, to disable a field: `document.getElementById("elementIDhere").disabled = true`.)

Comment: sorry guys i am new to this forum

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;"> Donation Form </button>
<button onclick="'" style="width:auto;"> <a href="index.html"> Adoption Page  </a> </button>
    <div id="id01" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">×</span>
        <form class="modal-content animate" action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="container">

                  <label> <b> First Name: </b> </label>
                  <input name = "name" type = "text" size = "25" Placeholder=" Enter First Name" required />       
                  <label> <b> Last Name:</b> </label>
                  <input  type = "text" size = "25" placeholder="Enter Last Name" required />       
                  <label><b> Mailing address:</b> </label> 
                  <input  type = "text" size = "25" placeholder=" Enter Home Address" name="Address" required/> 
                  <label> <b> Date of Birth:</b> </label>
                  <input  type = "text" size = "25"  placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" name="DOB"/>
                  <label> <b> Telephone Number:</b> </label> 
                  <input  type = "text" size = "25" placeholder="Enter Contact Number" name="Tnumber"/>
                  <br>
                  <label><b>Email</b></label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Address" name="email" required>


                  <p><b>  What type of donation would you like to make  </b> <p/>

                  <select name = "donations">
                                <option selected = " selected">------</option> 
                                <option>Animal </option>
                                <option>Monetary</option>
                                <option>Services</option>

                  <br /> <br />

                  <div id="animal" style ="visibility: hidden;" > 
                  <p> <b>Choose the type of Pet you would like to Donate: </b> </p>

                  <label> Dog <input name = "Pet" align="right" type ="checkbox" value= "Dog " align="right"/></label> 
                  <label> Cat <input name = "Pet" type ="checkbox" value= "Cat" /> </label>
                  <label>Snake <input name = "Pet" type ="checkbox" value= "Snake" />
                  <label> Hamster <input name = "Pet" align="right" type ="checkbox" value= "Hampster " /></label> <br/>
                  </div>






            <div class="clearfix">
                    <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel form </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="submitbtn">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}

     var selected = document.query.selector('#select-donation');
     var animals = document.query.selector('#select-animal');
     var monetary = document.query.selector('select-monetary);
     var service = document.query.selector ('select-service');

     function showlist(){
        if (selected.selectedIndex == 1 )
        { animals.removeAtrribute('disabled');
        monetary.disabled= true;
        service.disabled= true; }
        else if (selected.selectedIndex === 2) 
        { monetary.removeAtrribute('disabled');
        animal.disabled = true;
        service.disabled= true; }
        else if (selected.selectedIndex == 3)
        {service.removeAtrribute ('disabled');
        animal.disabled = true; 
        monetary.disabled = true; }
        }


</script>
```